# Delete temp file during finally vs delete output file during catch

Tags: java, file-io

This is in Java 6.

I've seen more than once that people create temp files, do something, then rename it to the output file. Everything is wrapped in a try-finally block, where the temp file is deleted in `finally` in case something goes wrong in between.

```
try {
    //do something with tempFile
    //do something with tempFile
    //do something with tempFile
    tempFile.renameTo(outputFile);
}
finally {
    if (tempFile.exists())
        tempFile.delete()
}
```

I was wondering what are the benefits of doing that instead of doing something to the output file directly and delete it in case of exceptions.

```
try {
    //do something with outputFile
    //do something with outputFile
    //do something with outputFile
}
catch (Exception e) {
    if (outputFile.exists())
        outputFile.delete();
}
```

My guess is that deleting temp files in `finally` benefits me when the try block can throw many kinds of exceptions. Is my guess right? What else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`finally` is always executed while the `catch` above is not executed for exceptions that derive from `java.lang.Error` plus it will delete the file also when it can't be renamed (this operation doesn't throw an exception when it fails ... an ancient bug in Java IO).

Comment: In addition, the catch above is also not executed in case of normal execution (no Throwable thrown), while finally gets executed either way.

Comment: so if I instead catched `Throwable` (although not recommended) and checked the return values from `renameTo`. The case with no `finally` will act a little more similar to the case with `finally` right? +1 because you seem to be the only one to answer my (vague) question at a high-level rather than teaching me the difference between `catch` and `finally` (which I also appreciate anyway).

Comment: Nope. You forgot that someone can call `return` in the `try` block. So you see that the solution with `finally` *always* works while any other solution *mostly* works.

Answer (score 3):

Working with the temp file until the operation is complete will insure you are not ending up with an output file which is partly modified.

In addition the finally block will execute regardless of the outcome while the catch block will only take place when an exception surfaces.

A more in depth example would be...

```
try {
    //do something with tempFile

    //operation is complete since we made it this far; transition
    //tempFile into outputFile
    tempFile.renameTo(outputFile);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    //perform error logic
}
finally {
    if (tempFile.exists())
        tempFile.delete()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but in any case, both of my examples should not result in a corrupted `outputFile`, would it?

Comment: @Russell It depends if an outputFile exists and is being overwritten. If that was the case then you would remove the existing outputFile in the second example. If no file exists then in your second example there is nothing to corrupt since you are deleting the file should an exception surface.

Answer (score 2):

finally *always* executes, so the difference is that in the first case that file is always deleted (for both normal execution and exception thrown). If you only want to delete that file if something went wrong, go with deleting in the catch block.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry my question was unclear, so let me clarify. My goal was to prevent a corrupted `outputFile`. I was wondering if you had any input on the two approaches, i.e. creating a temp file then renaming it versus creating an output file and delete if when errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know delete/copy and other file operations are done via the OS API and there is no guaranty that those APIs work at the moment. for example if your own program and any other program keep the temp file open, the API won't be able to delete the file. So in the case of working with TEMP file if this happens user won't have the bad file, instead have a temp file and he/she has no idea about what the file is for, but if you work directly with the main file, in the case of any failure in deleting the file, your user will have a file which contains bad data, **I think**